# What is the reason behind the 6 character minimum for suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Why must edits be at least 6 characters? There are some minor spelling mistakes which could be fixed by changing less than 6 characters; I think it would be nice to include them.

Comment: Edits bump questions to the front page. Accepted suggested edits can gain the suggester 2 rep (depending on current rep). We don't want trivial edits. Rarely is there a post that the only thing that requires fixing is within 6 characters.

Comment: You can _always_ find 6 to change... see edit.

Comment: @Oded can we allow edits less than 6 characters without 2 rep? many times I just want to fix spelling mistakes only

Comment: *"many times I just want to fix spelling mistakes only"* ... please let all your edits be complete. If this means you can't edit some posts, feel free to skip them. Someone else will pick it up at some point. There is nothing more annoying than seeing a post bumped to the front page because of an incomplete edit. And generally there are more than 6 characters the fix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes sometimes there's that little itchy edit you want to make, but...

### Suggested edits make work for others

Each suggested edit has to be reviewed by multiple users to check it's OK, so we don't want to put people to the trouble for a single typo.

At 2000 rep you can make edits without review - it changes instantly.

### We want to encourage people to make substantial edits

It's much more useful to the community if folks get in the habit of editing every problem out of a post - phrasing, spelling, typos, layout, syntax highlighting, formatting etc.

Having a lower limit on the number of characters you can change flags this up early on. (And insubstantial suggested edits will be rejected as such.)

### Edits bump the question to the top of the homepage

Every time a question is edited, it goes to the top of the list. If tiny edits were allowed, this could happen too often, pushing more recently asked questions onto page 2.

### If you disagree and want things to change...

Firstly, I only answered the question to give information, not because I'm responsible for the policy in any way.

Some of you disagree with the policy and its reasoning and say so in comments to me here, but please understand firstly that the site prizes answers very much more than comments so you're using a rather  ineffective medium, and secondly I am powerless to change this anyway so trying to convince me is futile.

You'll find if you comment, it's probably only me that's guaranteed to read it because it's hidden in the unexpanded comment list, and I don't use the site nearly as much as I used to when I wrote this explanation all those years ago.

If you want to make change, you'd be better off making an alternative answer that's well reasoned in support of your solution, or if that's already happened, upvoting it and maybe editing it to better support your point.

Comment: In my opinion even small edits can improve the quality of a question (for instance fixing a broken or outdated link). Seem that most of the objections arise because all the edits are considered as equal. Maybe the editor could be given a choice to classify the edit as "substantial edit" or "typo corrections" each category with different rules (typo may not reward the editor,  bump the question on top, and may have shorter review paths)...

Comment: Completely agree with @Gab. Consider block of code (`one-liner`) which is not formatted. To fix it we have to change more characters - that's wrong. 2k rep is not solution.
Check this revision: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/185955/revisions

Comment: Typos and other minor errors degrade communication, and the current policy ensures that many of them will go unfixed. I'm confident that with a little creative thinking Stack Overflow can figure out how to engineer a system that allows edits of less than six characters while still satisfying all the design constraints enumerated above.

Comment: @AndrewC "Suggested edits make work for others" -- i was told the poster could also approve the edit. Is that not true? And, if the edit makes the difference between a correct answer and an incorrect one, and if SO goal is to improve content quality, then why do you object to the extra 'work'? "We want to encourage people to make substantial edits" -- if changing one character makes an incorrect post correct, how is that not "substantial?" "Edits bump the question to the top of the homepage" --then don't do that. That's not a compelling reason to preserve an incorrect post.