# What should I do if my edit is less than 6 characters for an over 100 upvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I found a typo on a 127 upvote accepted answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous/2035662#2035662).

> Iti's more accurate to say that Javascript is synchronous and single-threaded with various callback mechanisms.

It should be:

It's more accurate to say that Javascript is synchronous and single-threaded with various callback mechanisms.

As a Stack Overflow user less than 2k reputations, I can't submit my edit because **Edits must be at least 6 characters;**

This question is not duplicated with [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251580/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-6-character-minimum-for-suggested-edits) because:

I am asking what I should do about this 127 upvoted accepted answer with a typo not the reason why edits must be at least 6 characters.

> Fixing grammatical or spelling mistakes is encouraged!

I want to improve the quality of this answer since this post will be seen for a large number of web developers.

What should I do?

Comment: In a nutshell, you can almost always find other things that could be touched up, so you should almost never be hampered by the 6 character limit.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I am not a native English speak. So finding a typo is all I can do for this post. I will certainly try my best. However, rephrasing is not what I am good at it. Hope you understand.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin that does make it harder to find improvements.  You could always just comment on the post asking the author to fix the typo.  In this case, the author is still active on SO, so they will see your comment.

Comment: @ryanyuyu This is actually a very good suggestion!

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the questions above; those are asking why there is a restriction. This question is asking what to do when you bump into that restriction. Similar but distinct questions.

Comment: @TylerH: this has been discussed before (possibly on Meta-SE). The consensus seems to be to *fix everything you can* until you have enough reputation to not have the restriction anymore. And if you can only see 1 thing to edit, just leave it and find another post to fix. See also [How do I make a good edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/2564301).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out there are many typos in this answer; more than enough to make 6 characters worth of edits. You should look more closely! :-)

- JavaScript was written as Javascript in every occurrence
- Iti's was a typo that you spotted. That could have been changed to "It is" or "It's"
- There were two spaces after a period/full stop in one instance (that's a holdover from the typewriter era and is ignored by all web browsers, so it's superfluous and should be removed)
- The last sentence of the answer said "included all event handlers [...]" and it should have been "includ*ing* all event handlers [...]"
- I also happened to change AJAX to Ajax as the original and primary way to refer to the technology.

In situations where there truly is not enough to change, you should leave a comment under the post pointing out the error.

PS - Your profile has some typos in it: "digitial" should be "digital", "StackOverFlow" should be "Stack Overflow", "wondering" should be "wandering" (per Rad Lexus), and "pushing" should be "pushes".

Comment: (On your PS: also, 'wondering' > 'wandering'; 'part' > 'parts'.)

Comment: To be fair, the double-space after the full stop wasn't there until my (apparently incomplete) edit.  That was my fault.

Comment: @RadLexus Nice catch! I only skimmed it

Comment: @TylerH Thank you suggestions!

Comment: I will pay closely attention on all the unique words such as JavaScript, Stack Overflow. It will be nice to have a post about these.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin There is a post out there on Meta Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Exchange about SO names. As for others, you can always defer to what they're written as on their Wikipedia article or their website, if they have one (like React or AngularJS).

Comment: Regarding the AJAX vs. Ajax issue: The [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info) consistently talks about AJAX. Shouldn't it be adapted then?

Comment: @honk The tag verbiage is a separate matter from referencing the technology in general prose. I agree that the tag info should probably be updated, but I'm under 20k (or whatever the tag edit privilege is) and it's not really a pressing concern for me to make the edit as a suggested edit.

Comment: @TylerH: Maybe it's a different matter, but when I type keywords that are represented by tags and that I'm not fully familiar with, then I usually look at the tag excerpts to infer the correct capitalization. Others might do the same. So, if we strive for consistency, an update of the tag info would be nice. Are you afraid of making suggested edits? ;)

Comment: @honk No, I just don't have the time at the moment to invest in a quality edit, which likely will require more than just changing the case.

Comment: @TylerH: I suspected that same. But as I have no clue about Ajax, I won't do it by myself, either. Let's hope that somebody else reads this ;)