# Suggestion: relax minimum edit when editing your own recent changes

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I understand why there is a minimum change when you edit an answer.  You can't just change one character, you have to change at least ten characters or whatever the limit is.  This is a useful feature as it prompts you to improve the answer more generally.

My suggestion is to relax this requirement for making changes to *your own edit*.  You may edit an answer, have the edit peer-reviewed, then spot a typo.  It would be nice to correct that.  You have already cleared the threshold for a minimum useful edit with your recent change.  And if there were some other improvement you could think of to the answer, you would surely have included it in your original edit.

So I suggest: if you go to edit an answer, and in fact you have already edited it (and been peer reviewed successfully) in the past couple of days, small further edits will not have to pass the threshold on a minimum number of characters.  (It can still be a prompt, but not a hard requirement in this case.)

Comment: Couldn't that become an exploit? 1. Suggest an edit with a tiny tweak + 10 garbage characters; 2. Iteratively edit your suggestion to remove the garbage characters; 3. ??? 4. Waffles.

Comment: I don't think the suggested edits queue will welcome such small edits for peer reviews.

Answer (score 10):

Each edit needs to be considered in isolation. It doesn't matter that your previous edit already went through the review queue was approved, your new edit would have to go through the review queue **again**, but this time maybe *for a single character change*.

Not very reasonable.

Or maybe you are suggesting that further changes should be exempted from review altogether? Why would that be?

If the edit you need to make is too small and you do not have yet full edit privileges, just move on and leave it for someone else.

Comment: I expected they'd still be peer reviewed.  I believe the proposed change would lessen the load on the review queue, not increase it.  Currently if I want to go back and fix a minor typo or omission in my recent edit, I must add ten characters of "noise" to the edit to pass the filter.  That creates extra work for the reviewers.  Better to just fix the typo or add the missing word -- which can then be reviewed in itself, without the extra bloat.

Comment: _I must add ten characters of "noise" to the edit to pass the filter_. You must certainly **NOT**. Just let it be, and someone else will fix it.

Comment: That's exactly the point I am making.  The site does not allow you to submit the edit unless it changes at least ten characters (or some similar threshold).  For example, I recently edited an answer adding a terminal transcript to illustrate my point.  But I forgot to include the final printed output of the command, making the example a bit pointless.  (The reviewer didn't catch that mistake either, I only spotted it after review.)  Since that was just four characters, I could either leave the answer incomplete, or add some "noise" to allow the edit.

Comment: @EdAvis Again, you are **doing it wrong**. If you need to add noise to be able to make an edit, just **do not suggest the edit**. Leave a comment if you want, and a user with full edit privileges will do it for you, or even the post author.

Comment: P.S. in programming a single character change can be highly significant...

Comment: Really? I wouldn't have known. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @EdAvis On a programming website, such statements are going to generally be seen as condescending.  Assuming that they know what they're talking about is going to make for a much better approach.

Comment: I guess what I'm missing is the rationale for the six character limit.  I had thought it was to encourage people to clean up an answer more generally when editing it.  But from your replies it looks like there is some other motivation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't intend to appear condescending -- just to note that I have often written code that was plain wrong, and changing 0 to 1 (or whatever) fixed it, so this could certainly be a useful edit to make in and of itself.

Comment: @EdAvis Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251580/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-6-character-minimum-for-suggested-edits), or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179873/why-should-an-edit-be-of-at-least-6-characters). When doing a feature request, it is always better to do as much research as possible. The site has a lot of traffic and of _feature-oriented_ users, so most of the FRs one can think of have been discussed in one way or another in the past.

Comment: Thanks -- I agree with those reasons, but I think that "we want to improve the answer more generally" cannot apply so much in this particular case -- after all you just edited the answer very recently, so you already improved it as much as you are able.  I didn't know that any edit would bump the question, indeed I would probably prefer not to do that, but it's not my call.