# What should I do if I have a legitimate edit that changes less than 6 characters?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

This happened to me lots of times:

- Someone wrote "fidning" instead of "finding", normal typo, he/she himself/herself would have approved that edit.
- Syntax correction; something like '!#/bin/bash' to '#!/bin/bash' (it was obvious that this was an error when posting the question, because his/her posted error was one including the line with the real issue)
- Fixing markup: Very often the OP has it all right, but the OP does not know that it needs two blanks or two linefeeds to separate the two paragraphs. - Often it is the four blanks that are missing, making it almost unreadable as inline text.

Some of those edits are important (to others).

Sometimes I "invent" some changes that do not change a thing, like changing a word to a synonym, or rearranging a sentence ("with ab xy does not work" to "xy does not work with ab").

Why do I have to make unimportant changes that affect at least five letters, just to fix a real issue?

Even with enough reputation points, should I really post comments like: "you misspelled finding as fidning"?

What is the right thing to do?

---

Addition: I have only found [this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251580/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-6-character-minimum-for-suggested-edits), but I already was convinced that the 6-char-minimum is a good/necessary thing.

Comment: There's usually more to fix than 6 characters.

Comment: Regarding the second error: do not edit those typos in **questions**. As "sure" as you are, is up to the OP to post their question. If you fix their code for them, you may be hiding issues that are pertinent to the question but you are not aware of.

Comment: *Sometimes I "invent" some changes that do not change a thing, like changing a word to a synonym, or rearranging a sentence...* You risk getting your suggestions rejected by doing that because it looks like you either think the original was somehow wrong (esp. if your edit summary only mentions grammar and spelling) or you're making style changes that don't improve the post at all.

Answer (score 12):

Until you have enough reputation for auto-approve edits, leave a comment and move along. Let the OP, or someone with enough reputation, handle it. This way, the reasons that justify the 6-character limit are also respected.